# What drive partition type supports chmod-ing, 2tb drives and windows (no 3rd party software)?

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, formatting

I have a 2tb drive that needs to support Linux chmod-ing and windows 7. What format supports both? (I can't use 3rd party software on my windows machine.)

Comment: pretty sure Linux supports NTFS these days? That would be your only choice with Windows.

Comment: Yes, but NTFS does not support permissions.

Comment: Actually it does its just that NTFS on Windows uses ACLs with IDs specfic to Windows users. You can add support for ACLs in Linux but thats only half the battle. So for example the fact that your Linux user 1000 owns file A means absolutely nothing to Windows and visa versa. Take a look at this question for ideas of how to integrate this if thats what you want:https://askubuntu.com/questions/301494/how-to-change-ntfs-acls-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

Use NTFS with the `ntfs-3g` driver on Linux.

However, remember that Windows and Linux use very different ACL formats (at least without RichACL patches), so the mapping from Windows-style to POSIX-style is troublesome and disabled by default. See [NTFS-3G documentation](https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/) for details.

---

In short, to activate this feature you need to create a `UserMapping` file which maps Windows SIDs to Linux UIDs. By default ntfs-3g will look for it at:

```
<diskroot>/.NTFS-3G/UserMapping
```

The format is `<LinuxUser>:<LinuxGroup>:<WindowsSID>`. If you already have Windows users which must correspond to Linux users, you can find out your SID on Windows by using `whoami /all`. For example:

```
grawity::S-1-5-21-3249547053-3230652633-3112126503-1103
:users:S-1-5-21-3249547053-3230652633-3112126503-513
```

Also add a "default" entry at the end, so that unknown Linux UIDs will be mapped properly. (This one doesn't have to match your Windows SIDs.)

```
::S-1-5-21-3249547053-3230652633-3112126503-10000
```